# Python GPA Calculator

Tags: python, calculator

I'm working on a GPA calculator in python 2. However, I cannot get the code to work as I want. I was hoping if someone could me out and provide me some direction. When I put in grades I want it to calculate a GPA. Now, it only reads a letter or a symbol, but not both together. I'll put in A+ it'll give me .3 not 4.3. If I put in multiple grades, it'll only read the first grade.
The for part takes all the grades entered, and gives us the average GPA.

Here is the code:

```
from sys import argv

def gp(grade):
    points = 0
    if grade == 'A' or grade == 'a':
        points +=  4.0
    if grade == 'B' or grade == 'b':
        points += 3.0
    if grade == 'C' or grade == 'c':
        points += 2.0
    if grade =='D' or grade == 'd':
        points += 1.0
    if grade == 'F' or  grade =='f':
        points += 0.0
    if grade.endswith ('+'):
        points = points + 0.3
    if grade.endswith ('-'):
        points = points - 0.3
    for x in grade
        return points = sum(points)/len(grade)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    grade = argv[1].replace(" ","")
    print (("%.1f") % gp(grade))
```

Comment: How do you want it to work and how is it working now?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have you tried `grade[0] == 'A'`? From your code, it seems `grade` can be stuff like `A+`, and `'A+' != 'A'`

Comment: Also, what is `for x in grade return points = sum(points)/len(grade)` supposed to do?

Comment: the grade cannot end with two different characters and cannot be two  different characters at the same time

Comment: When I put in grades I want it to calculate a GPA. 
Now, it only reads a letter or a symbol, but not both together. I'll put in A+ it'll give me .3 not 4.3.

Comment: If I put in multiple grades, it'll only read the first grade

Comment: This refuses to compile, as written. Python 2.7.8
Also, I can't fix it easily. Try following the complaints of the python interpreter until your code works in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Since this looks like homework, I'm not going to give a solution.  But I will give a little bit more info about what is wrong.  Hopefully if you understand what is wrong, you will be able to figure out how to do it right.

If your grade is 'A+', then it is a string of 2 characters, the first of which is `A` and the second is `+`.  Can `grade=='A'` be true?  Once you understand that, it should be clear to you why `A+` isn't getting the 4 part of the grade.

As for why it's only giving you the result for the first grade, what does `argv[1]` become?  Is it all of the grades you send it?

Answer (score 0):

```
from sys import argv

def gp(grade):
    points = 0
    if grade.lower() == 'a':
        points +=  4.0
    if grade.lower() == 'b':
        points += 3.0
    if grade.lower() == 'c':
        points += 2.0
    if grade.lower() == 'd':
        points += 1.0
    if grade.lower() =='f':
        points += 0.0
    if grade[:0] == "+"
        points = points + 0.3
    if grade[:0] == "-"
        points = points - 0.3
    for x in grade
        return points = sum(points)/len(grade)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    grade = argv[1].replace(" ","")
    print (("%.1f") % gp(grade))
```

I "fixed" the if statements for the grade letters but you're here for the symbols so there.

Comment: [Code-only answers are discouraged.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272). It would be better to point out the lines to change, with explanation.

Answer (score -2):

```
'''This is a simple GPA calculator I was able to put together. Hope this help'''

class GpaCalculator():
    '''Declare the variables'''
    count = 0
    hrs   = 0
    numberofclasses =0
    totalhours = 0
    totalPoints = 0.0
    gpa = 0.0
    '''Prompt the user for the number of classes taking'''
    numberofclasses = int(input("Enter number of  classes "))

    '''use for to loop '''
    for count in range(count, numberofclasses):
        '''This is to keep track of the number of classes (Optional)'''
        print("For class # ", count+1)

        '''Prompt user for number of number of credit hours per class'''
        hrs = int(input("Enter the credit hrs "))

        '''Prompt user to enter the letter grade'''
        grade = input("Enter the letter grade ")

        '''Use if statement to check the grade and increment points and total hours'''

        if grade == 'A' or grade == 'a':
            totalPoints = totalPoints + (hrs * 4)
            totalhours = totalhours + hrs
        elif grade == 'B' or grade == 'b':
            totalPoints += (hrs * 3.0)
            totalhours += hrs
        elif grade == 'C' or grade == 'c':
            totalPoints += (hrs * 2.0)
            totalhours += hrs
        elif grade == 'D' or grade == 'd':
            totalPoints += (hrs * 1.0)
            totalhours += hrs
            '''If not A,B, C, D then it must be F. You can write validation to check in other lettes'''
        else:
            totalPoints += (hrs * 0.0)
            totalhours += hrs
    '''Calculate GPA based on the total points and total hours'''
    gpa = totalPoints / totalhours
    print("Your GPA is :", gpa)

def main():
    gpa = GpaCalculator()

if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```